# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType (tkinter error)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to read the file with tkinter button basically when button press the function will read the files if the files doesn't exists it will show an error if its exits than it will continue, but it throws me an error

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Here are the codes:

```
def ffr(driver,filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f= []
    for i in lines:
        f.append(i[:-1])
    wait = webdriver(driver, 10)
    for i in f:
        url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/"
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)

def follow_file():
    try:
        open('reading.txt')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        Error_box_follow_file_not_found()
```

The Button:

```
ff= Button(root,text="read file", command=lambda:ffr(driver,follow_file()))
ff.grid(column=1,row=19)
```

**Error box**

```
def Error_box_follow_file_not_found():
messagebox.showerror('insa', "Error: Please add file 'readline.txt' into path!")
messagebox.CANCEL
```

Comment: The problem is `follow_file()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: what i have to return? if you check the follow_file() i only trying to read the txt files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas bro @furas can you please help

Comment: I think `follow_file()` is useless. Why don't you just pass the filename directly to `ffr()` instead?

Comment: But i want to show an error if there is no such file.
basically if user click on the button and the file doesn't exits so i can tell the user to add file first to continue the task

Comment: you could do all directly in `ffr`. OR in `follow_file` run `ffr()`. But main problem is that `follow_file()` has to do `return 'reading.txt'`

Comment: if you want to check if file exists then you have `os.path.exists()`

Comment: if file doesn't exist then you run `Error_box_follow_file_not_found()` but it doesn't stop rest of code and it will run also `ffr(driver,filename)` which will raise error again. Better put all in one function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem: `follow_file()` has to `return` filename which will get `ffr(driver,filename)`

```
def follow_file():
    try:
        open('reading.txt')
        return 'reading.txt'  # <---
    except FileNotFoundError:
        Error_box_follow_file_not_found()
```

But this still have other problem.

If file doesn't exists then it run `Error_box_follow_file_not_found()` but later it exits this function with `return None` and it runs `ffr(driver, None)` and it will raise error. It would have to check `filename is not None` at start and skip rest of code.

```
def ffr(driver, filename):

    if filename:  # if filename is not None:
        f = open(filename)
        lines = f.read().split("\n")
        f.close()

        wait = webdriver(driver, 10)

        for i in lines:
            url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/"
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Frankly, I would do all in one function

```
def ffr(driver):

    try:
        f = open('reading.txt')
        lines = f.read().split("\n")
        f.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        Error_box_follow_file_not_found()
        return

    wait = webdriver(driver, 10)

    for i in lines:
        url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/"
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from selenium import webdriver

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

def error_box_follow_file_not_found():
    messagebox.showerror('insa', "Error: Please add file 'readline.txt' into path!")

def ffr(driver):

    try:
        f = open('reading.txt')
        lines = f.read().split("\n")
        f.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        error_box_follow_file_not_found()
        return

    wait = webdriver(driver, 10)

    for i in lines:
        url = f"https://www.instagram.com/{i}/"
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)

# --- main ---

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

root = tk.Tk()

ff = tk.Button(root, text="Read file", command=lambda:ffr(driver))
ff.grid(column=1, row=19)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey furas thanks for your reply, your code is working fine but the error is showing in terminal , what i want to show is when file not found the pop up box shows in window , please check i added a code above <3

Comment: your original error has nothing to do with `FileNotFoundError` and generate problem in `ffr` so it can't catch with try/except which is in `follow_file` so maybe this is the problem. You didn't create minimal working code so I couldn't test my version. Better create minimal working code so we could use it for tests.

Comment: check furas@tlen.pl email i sent you the full code, i can't share full codes here to protect my project
thanks

Comment: wait = webdriver(driver, 10) <--- this code was causing the problem after removing it, its working perfectly thanks bro , you always help me <3